# Insert the .tex file created through the knitter to main .tex file

Tags: knitr

I want to insert out put file (created in RStudio as .rnw file, then I complied, it creates the .tex file) into my main .tex file. But I got an error, hw we can do this?

Comment: How did you insert until now? Does the created `tex` file contain `\begin{document} … \end{document}` and perhaps some `\usepackage…` before? BTW the usual commands would be `\input{…}` or `\include{…}`. A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) could help us to help you.

Comment: I just used the \input{} command,  did not use any \usepackage. What should I use?

Comment: The first Latex error is: Can be used only in preamble.

Comment: Can we avoid the making them in Rstudio. Thank you very much for ur help

Comment: I do not know RStudio at all. Once again more verbously: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem (read the linked page). It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In your case add a short RStudio compiled TeX file, too.